# C# Regular expression pattern what this matches for

Tags: c#, regex

Can sombody explain what this regex will check for

```
Regex x = new Regex("{([^}]+)}");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks for a `{...}` with some (1 or more) `non-}` inside. If successful it puts the content of the `{...}` in capture group 1.

```
Regex x = new Regex("{([^}]+)}");
var m = x.Match("{Hello}");

string str0 = m.Groups[0].ToString(); // {Hello}
string str1 = m.Groups[1].ToString(); // Hello
```

Group 0 is always the whole match.

```
var m2 = x.Match("{}");
var success = m2.Success; // false
```

It isn't anchored, so it could have more than one match for each string...

```
var m2 = x.Matches("{Hello}{}{World}");
int c = m2.Count; // 2 matches. The {} wasn't a match, {Hello} and {World} were
```

As a sidenote, if you think this is the beginning for a good C# parser, you are on the wrong road :-) Expressions like `{ { string str = "Hello"; } str += "x"; }` will confuse this regex, so expressions like `{ string str = "}" }`. This is a stackless regex. No fancy tricks.

Answer (score 1):

It matches anything between curly braces, if there at least one character.

There is group `()` inside braces `{}`. This group should have at least one `[]+` symbol which is not closing brace `^}`.

Answer (score 1):

It matches anything between curly braces
eg
`{ddhhh13233dddd}` `{ddd}`

Answer (score 0):

This will catch everything within the curly brackets.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966.aspx) can explain it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This will catch everything within the curly brackets.

I find this tool is the best for explaining Regex's

http://tinyurl.com/lz3d458

[image]